# Can't reinstall SSH on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: apt, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was having issues getting SSH to work under my WSL Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, I was getting connection refused all the time, so I found [this suggestion in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3173), which is to just:

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
> sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
> ```

`remove` works, but `install` gives me:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass molly-guard rssh
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I tried, as suggested [in another issue on the same repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3664):

```
sudo dpkg --force depends -P lxd
sudo dpkg --force depends -P lxd-client
```

But it didn't work. How can I fix this and what is going on?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why, but it works

Comment: Ummmmm ... what works?

Comment: Someone posted something and deleted, probably a reference to a duplicated case.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the quick reply. It seems that the duplicate tells us to
`sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf`
which I hesitate to do without knowing exactly what's happening. Was that the solution that worked for you?

Comment: Honestly I can't remember.

Comment: I probably would have saved that file in another folder, instead of just deleting it, with the same fear that you have

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it works